# How to acccess a zip file stored in a bytes variable in Python 3?

Tags: python, base64, zip, byte, webservice-client

I am writting a Python script that consumes a Web Service in order to access some xml file stored in a zipped folder with 3 other xml files: zipfolder/myxmlfile.xml

The Web Service provides a method "GetResponse" that can be used to get the zipped folder in the form of base64 data, as explained in the documentation.

So I use this method as the following:

```
response = client.service.GetResponse()
```

- "response" if of class "bytes". Shouldn't it be base64 as described in the documentation?
- How can I access my xml file using this variable which presumably contains the zip file data?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `base64`:

```
import base64
bin = base64.b64decode(response)
with open('your_path/your_filename.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bin)
```

Comment: I tried. The zip file was created, yet it couldn't be opened : "not valid".

Comment: Can you give me the  base64 response to test it?

Comment: It has to do with the encoding it's maybe a `utf-16` but i cannot figure out exactly. I've worked with encode/decode of zip files with `base64` but this bytearray seems strange

Answer (score 0):

When I checked my "response" data I found out it wasn't base64, so I Base64 encoded it, then I Base64 decoded it. Finally, I wrote to a zip file and it worked.

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(response)
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
with open('myzipfile.zip', 'wb') as f:
 f.write(decoded)
```

Comment: Well wouldn’t that return the same result when deciding again?